# I have not included wrl.h header file, but why that i can using namespace Microsoft::WRL

Tags: com, directx, c++-cx, wrl

In this cpp file, I just include these head files

```
#include <D3D11.h> 
#include <d2d1.h> 
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <DXGI1_2.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <wincodecsdk.h>
#include <D2d1helper.h>
#include <Shcore.h>
```

Where is the wrl.h? Or is there option for this?

Comment: Most likely one of those other header files is itself `#include`ing wrl.h. Selectively comment them out to see which one.

Comment: Did you omit the pre-compiled header form your list (pch.h / stdafx.h)? If so, perhaps it is included there. On my machine, #including only the files in your list and `using namespace Microsoft::WRL` produces [error C2653](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4867f7c.aspx).

Comment: @MooseBoys There is no wrl.h in the pch.h file.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the compiler option /showIncludes to figure out where wrl.h is being included from.  During build this will show you a space-indented tree view of which files include which other files.  Make sure to do a rebuild and not just an incremental build, as the additional include might be coming from your pch.

If the include is at the top level, you might check your other compiler options to see if something is using /FI to include the file on the commandline.

(For the record, I tried with just the header files above and VS 2012 on Win8, and I did not see wrl.h being included.  So that header file must be getting included by something else.)